# Using Service Broker internal to a single SQL Express instance?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-express, service-broker

I understand that SQL Express cannot send Service Broker messages to other instances without a Standard (or better) instance involved in the chain.  But is it possible to use Service Broker to send and receive messages *within* a single Express instance?  In other words, the queues and services are all owned by (and never leave) the initiating SQL instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I understand the limitation only applies when you attempt to send messages outside of the instance. Sending messages within the same instance is not limited by using Express. See the last reply in the following link:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlservicebroker/thread/3b03a610-8159-4be8-b2d8-e2abb4ba1225

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks!  I had seen a similar link, but not that one.  A comment from Remus Rusanu is definitive, of course!  :)